# Allow only class/object methods in function signature in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function signature in Typescript. It is a sort of calling function that receives object, its method name and args to be applied.

Example of using:

```javascript
const obj = {
  do(...args) {
    console.log(args);
  }
}

call(obj, 'do', 1, 2, 3);
```

I can imagine a simple signature that defines that second parameter should be a property of first, but it's quite hard for me to disallow all properties that are not methods and specify that variadic arguments are this method's arguments.

```typescript
function call<T, P extends keyof T, A extends any[]>(obj: T, property: P, ...args: A): void;
```

Is it possible to do it with current Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not very complicated to extract the arguments of a function if we use [tuples in rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897). In fact in 3.2 Typescript uses this approach to implement strict `call`, `bind` and `apply` (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028))

To restrict the keys to we can restrict `T` to be a record with `P` keys that are function:

```
const obj = {
    do(...args: string[]) {
        console.log(args);
    },
    other(o: string, n: number) {
        console.log(o);
    },
    prop: 1
}

function call<T extends Record<P, (...a: any[]) => any>, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, property: P, ...args: Parameters<T[P]>): ReturnType<T[P]> {
    return obj[property](...args);
}
call(obj, 'do', 1, 2, 3); // error
call(obj, 'do', '1'); // ok
call(obj, 'do', '1', '2'); // ok
call(obj, 'other', '1', 2); // ok
call(obj, 'prop'); // error
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Didn't know that `Parameters` are already implemented!